# Magento configurable attribute with scope Global

Tags: magento-1.8, php

We are using configurable attributes that have the scope Global. Is it correct that he then shows the Admin label in the cart for the item options?

Update: It does work on the product page, the correct label shows but in the cart it always shows the admin label

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can test this to find out by navigating to a product that has this attribute and changing stores to verify.  No, it ***will*** change based on Store View even though it's a Global attribute.  If you change to your "Colsafety" view then it will output "Color"

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that on the product page is shows correct but on the cart it takes the admin label

Comment: You may have edited your checkout template to not use ` $this->__()` to render the item name so it's not picking up the translation. Try going back to the base/default checkout by removing that from your custom theme.